# RSYNC recursive over Time Machine Backups identify unique files

Tags: macos, time-machine, rsync

i have an issue with my Time Machine Backup. To fix the mess i thought about waling recursively over all TimeMachine Backup folders.

```
Oldest Backup
RSYNC to NEW_TARGET
```

Recursively go over every Backup folder (Oldest Backup +x Days) and only copy files which don't exist on NEW_TARGET.

But there's a pitfall. The folder names got changed so:

```
"insurances"
```

in the Oldest Backup Folder might be renamed to

```
"insurences new"
```

on a more recent backup folder but might contain a lot of same files AND NEW files. So i'm looking for a solution which could handle renamed folders in some way.

I hope someone has a clue how to achieve a solution.

Chris

Comment: Do you intend to modify the Time Machine back-up directly? Do you expect to restore Time Machine functionality on the files after this process? Could you break down the problem and fix the renamed folders separately to the merge?

Comment: Hi Graham, i could modify the Backup Folders on Time Machine but there are a lot. 200 Folders. I'm willing to modify those folders so that same folders (logical same) are named the same. This might help rsync a lot i guess :) I don't intend to use the disk for backup again, i just want a clean output of all unique files (and if possible folder structure) so to start over with a fresh disk for backups.

Comment: Which issue do you have with your TM backup? Maybe it's easier to fix this than to manually trying to reconstruct something with `rsync`, especially because TM works with multiple links to the same (unchanged) file, not with copies.

Comment: Yeah that's an issue i have in mind how to cope with the symbolic links.

The Backup sometimes did not transfer all files/folders. There are Backup Folders which differ from day to day basis. Like "insurences" folder is present the one day but not the other day.

Comment: I was more looking at the way TM organizes the backup drive (and uses hard links for files which do not change between backups). Overall I doubt that you get the backup back into a sane state, so getting another disk and starting over might be the less riskier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me:

```
rsync -abviuPEh --stats
```

did the job.

a = archive
b = backup (preexisting files will be appended by default with ~)
v = verbose
i = itemize (displays a summary what rsync did with a file)
u = update (skip files that are newer on the dest)
P = partial/progress
E = extended attributes for HFS+ Mac OS X
h = human readable output

Answer (score 2):

Modifying Time Machine back-ups directly is difficult. Time Machine uses [hard links and other tricks to work](http://pondini.org/TM/Works.html). So probably best to try and reconstruct the contents on a new drive.

I would divide the problem into parts:

- Fix the folder names
- Merge the folder contents

### Renaming

You can automate the renaming of files and folders matching specific patterns. See [Rename multiple files by replacing a particular pattern in the filenames using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840332/rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-a-particular-pattern-in-the-filenames-using-a) for a collection of approaches.

You could also use AppleScript or Automator for this task, if you need more involved logic.

### Merging

[rsync](http://rsync.samba.org) is probably a good starting point for extracting the contents from the Time Machine drive:

- [which is the rsync command to «smartly» merge two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/547282/which-is-the-rsync-command-to-smartly-merge-two-folders)
- [Synchronizing folders with rsync](http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2010/11/synchronizing-folders-with-rsync.html)

If `rsync` does not quite provide enough for your needs, consider [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

`unison` is designed to keep folders synchronised, with the merging taking care to ensure the destination contains only the latest files. Unison can be used on [local folders](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#local).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
Finally i went with:

`rsync -abviuPEh --stats`

It did a really great job and was case insensitive. So if a folder was name "CAR" and on the destination it was "Car" rsync merged the folders.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you mark the answer as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work